# UK visit visa and dependent and trip cost

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I live with my parents but i earn my own salary.
My parents are applyjng their visitor visa and i  also applying mine with them, i will mention my employment and i am not my father dependent , as stated in his application, but when they ask who will paying towards your visa application fee and i will want to write father name, and the total 1500 gbp he will be paying  ( aa his bank statement has enough balance ) is that right ?

Comment: It’s right if that’s how much your father will be contributing towards the costs of your trip. Since you’re travelling together you should quote your father’s GWF number in your application.

Comment: @Traveller want to create an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes my father bank statement had almost 20 000 GBP balance in current account and that balance was used to show enough money for him my mother and me for UK trip of 6 month visitor visa.
I submitted my bank statement to show my salary and little balance it had like 1300 GBP. Visa approved.